# How to dynamically change component visibility in ExtJS

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6

I have a viewport define like this with a tabpanel

```
Ext.define('rgpd.view.Viewport', {
    extend: 'Ext.container.Viewport',
    layout: 'border',
    requires: [
        'rgpd.view.entity1.View',
        'rgpd.view.entity2.View',
        'rgpd.view.entity3.View',
        'rgpd.view.entity4.View',
        'rgpd.view.entity5.View',
    ],
    items: [{
        xtype: 'tabpanel',
        id: 'Rgpd',
        region: 'center',
        tabPosition: 'left',
        titleRotation: 0,
        tabRotation: 0,
        padding: 0,
        margin: 0,
        split: true,
        header: {
            layout: {
                align: 'stretchmax'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'RGPD',
                flex: 0
            },
            glyph: 124,
            items: []
        },
        config:{
            collapsible: true,
            hideCollapseTool: false,
            split:false
        },
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'entity1',
                textAlign: 'right',
                flex: 1,
                hidden: true,
            },
            {
                xtype: 'entity2',
                textAlign: 'right',
                flex: 1,
                hidden: true,
            },
            {
                xtype: 'entity3',
                textAlign: 'right',
                flex: 1,
                hidden: true,
            },
            {
                xtype: 'entity4',
                textAlign: 'right',
                flex: 1,
                hidden: true,
            },
            {
                xtype: 'entity5',
                textAlign: 'right',
                flex: 1,
                hidden: true,
            },
        ]
    }]
});

if (condition) {
    // set entity2 hidden: false
}
```

as you can see my items are hidden. I made an authentification system and i want to be able to reset hidden to specific items (for example entity2) and set hidden to false. Is this possible and how ? I want to do it just after my viewport definition

[here is an example of what i want. Dynamically setting 2 entities at visible if the condition is ok and have this menu on left side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QTUgZ.png)

```
listeners: {
    boxready: function(){
         if(condition){
              this.down("entity1").setVisible(true);
              this.down("entity2").setVisible(true);
         }
    }
}
```

adding this piece of code produce [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wKFlu.png). I don't have the left menu and i have only one entity

Comment: You can use [`entity2.setHidden(false)`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.Component.html#method-setHidden) of  [`entity2.show()`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.Component.html#method-show)

Comment: @N.Jadhav same problem than with the first answer

Comment: only the first entity shows up if i set multiple ones to visible. And i don't have my menu on left side

Comment: So use same for the other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok here is how i did

```
this.getTabBar().getComponent(item_index).hide();
```

item_index can be found like this: you have `this.items.indexMap` which is an array where keys are the items xtypes and values are the index in items array.
set all the items to visible as default, make an array of items to hide

```
to hide = ["entity2", "entity3"];
```

loop on the array and make an index array

```
const arrayLength = to_hide.length;
arr = [];
for (let i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
    arr.push(this.items.indexMap[to_hide[i]]);
}
```

and then loop on the index array and hide each index

```
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    this.getTabBar().getComponent(arr[i]).hide();
}
```

getTabBar is specific for tabpanel

Answer (score 2):

Use [setVisible](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.Component.html#method-setVisible) function to change visibility of a component

add this to `tabPanel`

```
listeners: {
    boxready: function(){
         if(condition){
              this.down("entity1").setVisible(true);
              this.down("entity2").setVisible(true);
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is "down" ?

Comment: It's a function to find child items of a container with a selector https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/modern/Ext.Container.html#method-down

Comment: "TypeError: this.down is not a function " i get this in firefox console

Comment: in the wrong place probably. Just after viewport definition 
check the last lines of the code sample i've given

Comment: juste saw. I get a new issue. If i do this with multiple entities only one shows up and i don't have the menu on left i have if i set everything as visible from beginning

Comment: by the way why you want to hide and show `tabpanel's` tabs when `tabpanel` will do it for you?

Comment: i have my auth system. It defines roles If you're admin you can see everything if you're user you can see some items but not all items. If there is an other way to do post it as an answer

Comment: told you. Only the first entity shows up if i do it for multiple entities. and i don't have my "list" of entities on te left side of the screen

Comment: watch my original post at the bottom there is link of what i want (on the screen two entities are set to visible)

Comment: if you want the entity1 and entity2 to be visible run `this.down("entity1").setVisible(true);` and `this.down("entity2").setVisible(true);` actually i don't get what you are saying

Comment: that's what i did but you didn't read my answer. It doesn't produce the right result test the code you gave me i don't get the same thing than the image i uploaded

Comment: watch the ORIGINAL post

Comment: you did `this.down("entity1").setVisible(true);` twice. change "entity1" to "entity2" for second line

Comment: it's a mistake rewriting it . Still the same problem as described

Comment: send me a message in skype `faridmehr.hesam`

Comment: sent you a request